# How to get Content-Length or CRC in header of a web page?

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers

I wrote a crawler for spesific dynamic website. All crawl jobs taking over 3 hours.
I want to control the page is already crawled or there are some changes on page.
If i can do this the script will be completed in very short time.

for example:

```
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        if(thereAreChanges($url)){
            crawl($url);
        }
    }
```

Information: The web page doesn't provide content-length and crc.

```
Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
        [Date] => Tue, 08 Jan 2013 07:47:03 GMT 
        [Server] => Apache 
        [Set-Cookie] => Array ( 
                [0] => PHPSESSID=eisb6qjme9b0ouoga9su9fgok4; path=/  
                [1] => j12011=a%3A3%3A%7Bs%3A3%3A%22sid%22%3Bs%3A26%3A%22eisb6qjme9b0ouoga9su9fgok4%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%22ip%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%2294.103.47.65%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22time%22%3Bi%3A1357631223%3B%7D; expires=Sat, 09-Mar-2013 07:47:03 GMT; path=/  
        ) 
        [Expires] => Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT 
        [Cache-Control] => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 
        [Pragma] => no-cache 
        [Vary] => Accept-Encoding 
        [Connection] => close 
        [Content-Type] => text/html 
)
```

The site provides Content-Type but doesnt provide Content-Length. How can i ask content-length to apache.

Update : http://urivalet.com/ can get content-length. I need this.

If i can get CRC code of page in header. It will be perfect. But I guess this is long shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is `'header'=>"Accept-Encoding: gzip"`

That's why header doesn't return Content-Length, with this parameter page returns content-length.

Comment: And how this helps in implementation of `thereAreChanges()` ?

Comment: since we cant reach crc. I decide to run script everyday if content length changed. And run script everyweek in any condition. If some string changed and content-length didnt changed my script won't be noticed until weekly run. This will decrease cpu-bw usage a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `thereAreChanges($url)` You can do the following,

1. When send a request send `If-modified-since` header with the last time you visit the page as parameter. This header will return `304` status code if its not modified.
2. Check the `Last-Modified` header of the response and compare with your current stored page's last modified date. If the content is newer fetch it.
3. If possible perform `HEAD` request with those headers. `GET` will give you all the content. But `HEAD` will just return headers. For such query only headers are needed.
  4.

Its better to use existing crawler and search engine framework than writing one.

Use Apaches [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) to crawl webpages, [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to search the indexed pages. Solr provides a HTTP interface where you can run query by PHP. For more flexibility you can use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/).

Here is a [tutorial](http://blog.building-blocks.com/building-a-search-engine-with-nutch-and-solr-in-10-minutes) on how to setup Nutch and Solr.

Comment: i'll check these but i already wrote the crawler. If these are can control the page is changed or not, it means i can do too. If there is no way to check this; my script will show better performance then these.

Comment: If you have just written a crawler. I can ensure it will not perform better than Nutch.

Comment: BTW, if you just want to scrape, crawler is not what you want.

Comment: Here is a result for you. 49.8682 seconds for 52 pages, parsing and mysql insert 816 times. The website's response time is slow average (0.9 sec).

Comment: Your answers are not really relevant.

Comment: @CanberkP Does your crawler handle expired pages, page modification dates, different type of redirection,  Locale, mime type, chunked response, transfer encoding? Also there are a lot more things to consider.

Comment: my crawler crawls the homepage of the website then spider looks for specific urls(not all of them) so my crawler doesnt need to hand expired pages. Also logs the page modification dates. Doesn't need to hand redirection because there are no pages has redirect and never be. Also all pages are html, no need for check mime type. Dont try to discredit my crawler. Because it has specific job to do. And it is doing his job well. Only need few modifications and my question was pretty clear. But your answers is not about to help. You are only googling some crawler's properties and discrediting.

Comment: I have added what you need to put in that function. Hope it helps.

Comment: your code doesn't work because the website which I crawling doesn't provide request. Btw even content-length looks enough for me. If i can get this content-length i can write an algorithm like ( if content length isnt same as before; crawl again; else if server is not busy (cpu,network etc.) crawl again; else do not crawl; But the site isnt provide content length. I update my question to check the result.

Comment: I dind't provide any code. Also site never provides request you send the request. The standard is to check those headers.  If its not sending content-length, it means the length is unknown. In that case you can not rely on content length. Also you can downlod the whole content and get the length.

Comment: Nah u are wrong. I am sure urivalet.com doesn't get whole content to print content-length. This is server-side calculation by apache or IIS. Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-length.php).